# How to know expected input and output in pickle file from scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

Here's how I load pickle file

```
f = open('latest_model_v1_2.pkl', 'rb')
mdl = pickle.load(f)
```

and the `mdl` is

```
logisticRegressionCV(Cs=[0.09090909090909091, 0.18181818181818182,
                         0.2727272727272727, 0.36363636363636365,
                         0.45454545454545453, 0.5454545454545454,
                         0.6363636363636364, 0.7272727272727273,
                         0.8181818181818182, 0.9090909090909091],
                     cv=5, max_iter=10000, penalty='l1', solver='liblinear')
```

I don't know the expected name of variable input thos machine learning model, how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know what parameters are expected in a parquet file, you can use `feature_names_in_` variable.

```py
pickled_model = pickle.load(open("path/to/pickle/file.pickle", "rb"))
pickled_model.feature_names_in_
```

output:

```bash
array(['engines', 'passenger_capacity', 'crew', 'review_scores_rating'],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

`mdl.predict(test_data)` will work. For more info refer this doc https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html

Comment: `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

Even I don't have NaN values

Comment: Can you check your input to the model, See whether its proper.

Comment: It is proper, its 10 columns and full of number between -2 to 2 (already normalize by WOE transformation)

Comment: Please edit the question, if you want to add more info. Can you please post the input you are passing to the model.

Comment: I found other documentation of the model, let me check first